# Is there a way to determine where a merge came from in TFS?

Tags: tfs

A file was merged from one branch to another (as merging implies) but it looks like the comment is wrong in what was merged.  Is there a way to see what changeset was actually merged for the changeset I'm looking at?

NOTE: it was done recently, so may be there are logs showing what actually happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes... you can find out!

Right click on the branch -> View History -> You should be able to see the list of changeset. Now, select the change set you want to track -> right click -> Track Changeset -> select the branch you want to compare and click Visualize.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before, but I didn't know how to use it.